# How can I do indexing in numpy over multiple samples?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a train dataset `traind` with the shape `(60000,28,28)`.
I want to slice out all samples `(60000)` which have a mean of `0.3` or bigger.
I tried this:

```
condition = (np.mean(traind[0:60000,:,:]) > 0.3)
subTraind = traind[condition]
```

but it throws me followed error:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 2-dimensional, but 3 were indexed
```

Is there a way to do a slicing with multiple index conditions?

Comment: Where exactly did the error occur.  Looks to me like it's the `traind[0:60000,:,:]` indexing, and `traind` is 2d, not the (60000,28,28) shape you claim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.mean` will compute the mean over the entire array by default. You want to compute mean along the last 2 axes only:

```
condition = traind.mean(axis=(1,2)) > 0.3
```